# Ubuntu core 16 fstab new entry lost upon reboot on raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, linux, ubuntu

I installed `Ubuntu core 16` image on `Raspberry pi 3`. When I added new entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount windows share upon reboot, that entry is lost. I looked at `df -h` output as shown below and it appears `/etc/fstab` is mounted to temp file system and upon reboot it deletes any custom entry I have added:

`tmpfs           461M  4.0K  461M   1% /etc/fstab`

Where can I find real `/etc/fstab` so I can edit that file and make permanent entry.

Comment: Ubuntu core is not a standard version of Ubuntu like the version you would run on a laptop. This may account for the odd mounting of /etc/fstab. are you sure that adding mount points via fstab is even supported?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually gave up and installed raspbarian on my RaspPi. It appears ubuntu core is very restrictive OS with lack of documentation on their site and didn't sound like worth spending days to figure out a problem. fstab on ubuntu core is generated on reboot / startup. So any chances you put will get over written up on reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but I ended up here when searching for a solution to editing the `fstab` file on Ubuntu Core. The short answer is you should use [`systemd.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) units, instead of `fstab`.